# JavaScript Local Storage Second Counter

Tags: javascript, html, time, local-storage, counter

my question is the following: Is it possible to create a second counter using local storage? I mean you load the page, the counter starts counting from 1 one by one. You reload the page at 5seconds, and the counter won't resets but continues the counting from 5. Is it possible?

I have a code with a simple sec counter, but I don't know how to make it workable with Local Storage

```js
var seconds = 0;
var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

function incrementSeconds() {
seconds += 1;
el.innerText = seconds;
}



var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='seconds-counter'> </div>
```

Comment: yes, using a real reference time, and anyway, the chances that a setInteval of one second really lasts 1 second are zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way ?

```html
<div id="seconds-counter">_</div>
<!-- button id="bt-stop-counter"> stop counter </button -->
```

```js
const 
  counterLimit  = 5  // <-- your counter limit value....
, div_s_counter = document.querySelector('#seconds-counter')
, btStopCounter = document.querySelector('#bt-stop-counter')
, timeRef_ls    = localStorage.getItem('counterVal') || 0
, timeRef       = (new Date()) - (timeRef_ls * 1000)
, CounterIntv   = setInterval(() =>
  {
  let seconds = Math.floor(((new Date()) - timeRef) / 1000)

  if (seconds >= counterLimit )  // stopCounter()
    {
    div_s_counter.textContent = seconds = counterLimit
    clearInterval( CounterIntv ) 
    }
  div_s_counter.textContent = seconds
  localStorage.setItem('counterVal', seconds.toString(10))
  }
  , 500)
;
div_s_counter.textContent = timeRef_ls

/* disable counter reset ------------------------------------
  {
  clearInterval( CounterIntv )          // to stop the counter
  localStorage.removeItem('counterVal') // remove the counter
  }

btStopCounter.onclick = stopCounter
------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: One more thing. I would like to do a simple condition which says `if(seconds == 5) {STOP_COUNTER}` but I don't know how to do it, because I'm not really experienced in Local Storage. Any idea how to stop the counter when it reaches 5?

Comment: @scrummy I added `if (seconds >= 5)  stopCounter()` .  localStorage is pretty simple => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: One last question, I promise. Is there any way to completely stop, or remove the counter, after it reaches 5? I mean you reload the page, and it starts counting to 5. After it reaches the 5 and reload the page the counter values is still 5 and won't continue the counting ever again.

Comment: @scrummy  but that's what my code does => `localStorage.removeItem('counterVal')` the counter is erased from the localSotrage. By reloading the page `F5` it restarts from zero

Comment: But I want that to never reset the counter after it reaches the 5.

Comment: @scrummy  ah!, ok, no problemo, I have updated my code for that ;)

Comment: I have to admit, you're the most helpful person I've ever met.

Comment: @scrummy absolutely not !, it's just that I'm in one of my rare good days

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

function incrementSeconds() {
    var counter = window.localStorage.getItem("counter") ?? 0;
    window.localStorage.setItem("counter", ++counter);
    el.innerText = counter;
}

var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
```